# Android Interpolator for Indeterminate ProgressBar?

Tags: android

I need to repeat Indeterminate Progress Bar visual funcionality in my app.
Nothing hard, I plan to use ValueAnimator, but I stuck with interpolation.
 I need interpolator that use ProgressBar in [Material Design](https://material.google.com/components/progress-activity.html#progress-activity-types-of-indicators) (**look into Indeterminate**). 
Does it exist inbox Android SDK? And how this class called?